# How to train software so it recognize the kind of object shown in a picture?

Tags: machine-learning

I want to detect one kind of object such as person in the picture,
who can tell me how to training a kind of people classifier for use,so we can use the classifier to detect people in any picture.

Comment: Do specify: do you wish to have the software differentiate between, say, a (any) person and a (any) cat, or do you need to differentiate (identify/recognize) between different persons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can take a look at viola-jones framework: [Viola-Jones Object Detection Framework at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola-Jones_object_detection_framework)

it's cvHaarDetectObjects() in OpenCV.

Answer (score 2):

It's a pretty vague question but i think you're looking for a good computer vision library. The gold standard is [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) (Open Source Computer Vision). That'll get you started, and there's lots of people that have done facial recognition with it.

If you want to tell two people apart, that's a hugely more complicated problem. You'll likely use some of the same tools, but you'll need much more complicated algos.